# How do I create a 'page' that creates and downloads a file from within a module

Tags: 7, files

I have mymodule.php which contains all the logic for my site.

I need to create something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493794/530585).

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$array = array(
    array("data11", "data12", "data13"),
    array("data21", "data22", "data23"),
    array("data31", "data32", "data23"));
outputCSV($array);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}
```

Generally I've been adding items to `mymodule_menu()`, `mymodule_theme()`, and directing it to a `mymodule_mypage()` function, and oftentimes a `mypage.tpl.php`.

This setup doesn't really make sense for what I need to do here, though.

I need a linke like `mysite.com/mypage` to generate/download the csv.

I don't think that headers will work in a `mymodule_mypage()` function, and the template files are not appropriate because they load headers/footers etc.

I could just create the php files separately and create links to them, but I'm trying to keep things within the module and with tidy URLs.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget anything you can do with PHP you can do with Drupal, so headers work in exactly the same way.

Adding a page callback which sets headers and exits the script (with `drupal_exit()`) is definitely the right way to do this:

```
function MYMODULE_MENU() {
  $items['mypage'] = array(
    'title' => 'CSV',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_deliver_csv'
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_deliver_csv() {
  // Full complement of headers so IE behaves
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\";" );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  // Print your CSV data here

  // Exit the script
  drupal_exit();
}
```